# How to correctly pass a String array as function argument?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I know this has been asked numerous times before. However, I'm unable to get rid of a warning.

```
void function (char** cppStringArray);
int main(void) {
    char cStringArray[5][512]={"","","","",""}; //Array of 5 Strings (char arrays) of 512 characters
    function (cStringArray); //warning: incompatible pointer type
    return 0;
}
```

How do I get rid of the warning? It works if I declare the Stringarray as `char* cStringArray[5]`.

Comment: You should not pass modifiable string without passing size information. Either use const or supply size

Comment: @stefanbachert I know I am supplying the size just did not include it in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string array will remain with those sizes then the best way is to use

```
void function (char (* cppStringArray)[512], size_t num_strings);
```

pass as

```
function(cStringArray, sizeof(*cStringArray)/sizeof(cStringArray));
```

Problem is that `char**` is not equivalent to `char (*)[512]`. The former is a pointer to pointer to char. The latter is a pointer to a block of 512 characters.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Apparently the parentheses around *cppStringArray are important. I was trying that without the parentheses!

Comment: @ajay i was talking about "parentheses around *cppStringArray " i.e. `void function (char (* cppStringArray)[512], size_t num_strings);` and not `void function (char *cppStringArray[512], size_t num_strings);`

Answer (score 1):

Define the function like below.

```
void function (char cppStringArray[5][512]);
```